# Xpath in UFT not working

Tags: object, xpath, identity, hp-uft

Below code is written in UFT 12.5 version and ran on open Web application(Google).

Object is not identified or no action performed in Test result

```
Browser("name:=Google").Page("title:=Google").WebEdit("xpath:=//INPUT[@name='q']").Set “test”
```

Any resolution?

Comment: Tried it with `INPUT` in lower case?

Answer (score 3):

You have made a typo in the code which is **“test”**. 
Just change your code from **“test”** to **"test"** and then it will work fine.
So the actual statement should be

```
Browser("name:=Google").Page("title:=Google").WebEdit("xpath:=//INPUT[@name='q']").Set "test"
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran above code after modifying double quotes after Set and it worked fine:

```
Browser("name:=Google").Page("title:=Google").WebEdit("xpath:=//INPUT[@name='q']").Set "test"
```

Still, Please check whether google page is already open or not, also check whether proper addin selected or not, make sure google page is opened after opening UFT.